# how to validate input strings with regex patterns in Directus 9

Tags: node.js, regex, vue.js, content-management-system, directus

I'm using [Directus CMS](https://directus.io/). This is one of the best CMS I've come to know so far in terms of usability, features, and extensibility and moreover, it is open source and free. The admin dashboard is amazing and responsive.

There is one thing I am struggling with for a while and that is validating `strings` against `regex` patterns such as validating a `URL` input, `emails`, `pin codes` or `mobile number` input.

If anyone has created a custom interface for the **directus 9**, please help me here!!

Answer (score 3):

To achieve a specific field validation in Directus 9, please use regex validation when you create the fields in your collection's data model.

To test an email, for example :

- Create a new field (called email)
- Go to validation tab, select regex validation and enter this expression :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

this is a standard regex email validation, you can find other regex covering different usecases on https://regexpattern.com for example.

See the attached captures below :

[Create a validation for field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RxA4.png)

[API POST test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqlrz.png)